# Detect a textbox's content has changed after date selection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to detect textbox's content changed after selection of date from datetime picker.

My code is like this -

```
<div class="display-flex">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfLastSight, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy", maxlength = 10, id = "txtLastSightTestDate" })
    <button type="button" class="btn-datepicker" id="cal" onclick="ShowCalander('txtLastSightTestDate')">
        <em class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></em>
    </button>
</div>
```

Jquery code -

```
function ShowCalander(CalenderId) {
    $('#' + CalenderId).datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose: true
    });
    $('#' + CalenderId).trigger('focus');
}
```

event of that detects changes in textbox

```
$('#txtLastSightTestDate').on('propertychange change keyup paste input', function() {
    // do your stuff
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

This function is capturing all the events except one time, when i select a date from date picker.

Is there any other way available to capture this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
$('#' + CalenderId).datepicker({
    onSelect: 
    }
});
```

You will need to add your function to the on select property